# Connected sum of Lagrangians also a Lagrangian?

Tags: algebraic-topology, symplectic-geometry

Given a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ and pair of compact Lagrangians submanifolds $L_1,L_2$ inside it, do we know that there is a Lagrangian submanifold in M homeomorphic to their connected sum $L_1 \#L_2?$

Comment: Do you assume that they intersect transervally at finitely many points?

Comment: And I assume by Lagrangian you always mean submanifolds and not immersion, right?

Comment: I was more thinking of two disjoint Lagrangian sumbanifolds, so I guess that should be trivially covered if you have proof for transverse ones.

Comment: In general you just can't, there are simple topological obstruction. For example in $\mathbb C^2$ you do not have embedded genus 2 Lagrangian, but there are lots of embedded Lagrangian tori.

Comment: I see. Correct me if I am wrong - the topological reasoning for $\mathbb{C}^2$ example is that one has a Weinstein neighborhood of L and hence self intersection of L is +/- Euler characteristic of it which is non zero (unless it is a torus), and on the other hand, one can displace L from itself in $\mathbb{C}^2$ so self-intersection is zero.

Comment: Yes, exactly. ${}{}$

Comment: Great, thanks! And are there known setups/conditions (on the ambient M and Lagrangians $L_1,L_2$) where one can do the connected sum?

Comment: If instead the two Lagrangians intersect transervally, one should (?) be able do a surgery, replacing a nbd of the intersection with a Lagrangian (for example a Lawlor neck). If I have time I will find where this is proved/described and post an answer.

Comment: The Lagrangian surgery is done in a paper of Lalonde and Sikorav and also a paper by Polterovich. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01896378
If two Lagrangians intersect transversely in a point, you can find a local model where they look like $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $i\mathbb{R}^n$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$. If you think of this as $T^*\mathbb{R}^n$, you obtain a Lagrangian by looking at the (singular) section given by the 1-form $d \log |q|$. This is asymptotic to the fibre at $0$ and is asymptotic to the 0-section for large values of $|q|$. After smoothing, this gives the neck region.